# Drools Guvnor: How do dates and times work?

Tags: java, jboss, rules, guvnor

I know Java and I know C#.

I am a noobie with the JBoss Drools "Guvnor" and just their DRL rules language in general.  I need a little help on how to use dates and times correctly in the LHS of rules.

For example, I have to assure data quality in a health care system.  Obviously, each patient has a DOB in their record and it is of type java.util.Date.

Okay, so say I want to ensure that the DOB in the data passed as Facts is indeed before today's date.  I know, for instance, in C#, you can get the current date/time by saying DateTime.Now.

I want to add a rule in Guvnor that says (and this is pseudo-code):

WHEN
    patient DOB is before NOW
THEN
    mark patient as valid

My Patient fact is:

declare Patient
    patientID: integer
    firstName: text
    lastName: text
    dateOfBirth: java.util.Date
end

I also have a Dose fact, with a patientID field to link it to what patient got what dose:

declare Dose
    doseID: integer
    patientID: integer
    administeredDate: java.util.Date
    amount: integer
end

Also, say a medication is released on a certain year, 1995, and I want to also check that a dose for a given patient is not administered prior to that year.

How do I do these two?  I've tried Googling and Googling but all I get is links to the (utterly-useless) Guvnor User Guide which is pretty badly-written in that it doesn't contain this basic information, i.e., how dates and times work and are written in DRL syntax.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As always there are more than one way to do this. Here is one.

```
function Date currentTime(){
  // The content of this method is Java
  return new Date();
}

RULE "my rule"
  WHEN 
    patient : Patient( dateOfBirth < currentTime() )
  THEN 
    // Everything in THEN part is Java
    patient.setValid(true);  // Notice I added a valid field into the fact type
    update(patient); 
END
```

The other rule you asked for

> Also, say a medication is released on a certain year, 1995, and I want to also check that a dose for a given patient is not administered prior to that year.

```
RULE "Second Rule"
  WHEN
    patient : Patient() 
    not Dose( patientId == patient.patientId, administeredDate < 01-Jan-1995 ) // The date format can be changed if you want to.
  WHEN
    System.out.println( "Patient " + patient.getFirstName + " " +patient.getLastName() + " was not given a dose before." );
END
```

The Guvnor user guide does not cover the language basics. You can find them from [here](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.5.0.Final/drools-expert-docs/html_single/index.html). Guvnor is meant to provide you guided editors for writing the DRL or storing the files containing DRL. You check what the guided rule would look like if it was written in DRL by pressing the "View Source" button that is in each asset editor that produces DRL.